# Push new table to heroku without having to reset existing database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, rails-postgresql

I'm at the early stages of learning RoR and working with Heroku.  So i have a fledging app with local and production databases.  I've used `pg:push` to create the initial production database but I appreciate this requires you to reset the db every time.  I now have a new table in my local db that I wish to push to production, but I don't want to reset and lose the data.

It seems I could create a back up from production and then reload that.  Or could if run `pg:pull` to get the data into my local db, and then run a `pg:push` so that when I add the new table I'm also reloading my existing data.

All of this seems a little long winded.  From some knowledge of php and mysql, I would have simply ran an SQL query to add the new table, is there not a similar way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are searching for is migrations:

```
class CreateProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :products do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.text :description

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

You can create migrations on your local development environment and then run them on the production server once you are satisfied. You can read about migrations more here:

[Active Record Migrations](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html)

Comment: I understand about migrations, the question is more around the fact I have migrated a new table locally,  and wish to update the production scheme to reflect it.

Comment: I think that is exactly what a migration is for. You run it locally, check if everything alright and then commit it in your repo, push it up to heroku and run there also. It is even safer than doing it 'manually' because you can rollback if something is not right.

Comment: Right ok.  Maybe what I don't understand is when you say run it on Heroku also?

Comment: Depending on your rails version you can run: `heroku run bundle exec rake db:migrate` for Rails4 or `heroku run bundle exec rails db:migrate` for Rails5

Comment: you'll need to have heroku toolbelt for this: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli

Comment: Ok let me try that.  I have Heroku CLI which I _think_ replaced toolbelt.

Comment: yeah, I'm always confused with the naming :)

Comment: Interesting running `heroku run bundle exec rails db:migrate` does appear to have created the table according to Terminal:

`Migrating to CreateTestings (20170401133204)
   (0.8ms)  BEGIN
== 20170401133204 CreateTestings: migrating ===================================
-- create_table(:testings)
   (4.0ms)  CREATE TABLE "testings" ("id" serial primary key, "created_at" timestamp NOT NULL, "updated_at" timestamp NOT NULL)
   -> 0.0045s
== 20170401133204 CreateTestings: migrated (0.0046s) ==========================`

Just can't see the table number increase in the Heroku UI

Comment: I lied, its just updated, I was obviously too quick on the refresh. 

Perfect, thanks for helping me through this. It was proving a hurdle.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use [pg_dump](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/app-pgdump.html) with the `--table` option to just dump out a single table. Save that to a `.sql` file and then run it on the database you want to import into.

In general, it isn't advisable to be porting data manually from development to production. As you may have noticed, migrations keep your database *structure* synced, but not the data.

If there is a set of particular database values that your application is expecting, and you want to set these up in any environment; you can set up [seed data](http://railscasts.com/episodes/179-seed-data?view=asciicast). Then it's a simple case of running `heroku run rake db:seed` to get that data into production.

Comment: Its really just the schema I want to update, not worried about the data in the table.  And I'm just thinking forwards to times when I might add new tables, or want to add columns to existing tables in production etc.  Am I missing something very simple!